# File not uploading to dropbox via python script

Tags: python

This problem is just a more in depth explanation of the other problem.

I put the code on github because it's quite a fair bit. I'm sorry for the inconvenience 
`https://github.com/lonehangman/mccdropdav/blob/master/views.py`

Line 100 onwards is where the problems start. For the past week I've tried and failed to upload a file from pages (on iPad) to dropbox through a webdav set up on Google App Engine (GAE).

I can view the contents of my dropbox but when I download or upload from my computer or iPad it always gives an error. I checked the logs and saw that there was a key error for line 110, so I tried to fix this by printing meta_entry, which I then realised was a non existent resource.
(Hence the `# make a fake Resource to ease our exporting`. On line 106).
This problem left me befuddled for days, but then my friend told me to remove line 152  `root.append(self.export_meta_entry(metadata,href=self.request.path)) # first response's href contains exactly what you asked for (relative path)`
Doing this got rid of the key error but still wouldn't let me upload to dropbox. The iPad tells me it's uploading but I check my dropbox but no new files are to be seen. Nor can I download files. 
The logs don't seem to be picking it up.

Can anyone please explain and try help (If you're not going to help don't bother writing stuff like 'go somewhere else' or 'learn python noob'.)

If there is any more information needed just ask.
I'm quite tired at the time of writing this so it does seemed a bit rushed.

Comment: In some case, building a minimal example to exhibit your problem may help you solve it by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not looking your entire app, but only your `put` method (calling Dropbox `put_file`)

```
def put(self):
        path = '/' + self.request_path
        self.client.put_file(ROOT, os.path.dirname(path), self.request.body_file, file_name=os.path.basename(path))
        self.response.set_status(201,'Created')
```

[Dropbox API tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/files#python) example of `put_file`

```
f = open('working-draft.txt')
response = client.put_file('/magnum-opus.txt', f)
print "uploaded:", response
```

as well as [`put_file` documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-python-sdk-1.4-docs/index.html#dropbox.client.DropboxClient.put_file) say the first argument of put_file is the complete path of the file in dropbox tree (including the name of the file), and the second argument is a file-like object.

So something like that may be better

```
self.client.put_file(path, self.request.body_file)
```

As you can see, you may look at the return value of `put_file` to get further information on what happened in your `put_file`call. You may adjust your response code according to the response from Dropbox.

Comment: It gives me an error  `put_file() takes at least 4 argumets (3 given)`.
What Should I do?

Comment: sorry, I imagined somewhere you were calling Dropbox `put_file` method. Here is wepapp `put_file` and you seems to never ask dropbox such a thing. I advice you to get an incremental approach to your program, starting with a small working local application and solve your challenges (webapp, auth...) once at time. You may read some pointers here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128554/ and ask more precise question next time.